# app:popupTheme= "@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"- Cannot be resolved to a variable

Tags: android

I am having a minor problem with a field with my XML file when developing my interface for Android Studio. When hovering over my `app:popupTheme= "@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"`, I am receiving an error message that signifies the field 'Cannot be resolved to a variable.

Answer (score 14):

Sorry for late reply still it can help others who will be looking for solution.

It is because you are refering to your style.xml and there must not be any tag named as ... so you need to add these lines in your style.xml and it will resolve

```html
 <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="AppTheme.PopupOverlay">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: Thank you kind sir. You are a life saver.

Comment: style AppTheme.PopupOverlay should not extend itself. Then How it resolve your problem?

Comment: it is just an example. the problem with that guy was he did not have any tag in style.xml he just needs a tag. and i have created a new tag named similar to parent tag so that if he has used it anywhere else it won't conflict.
Asked 3 years ago answered 3 years ago social platforms are really wired.

Answer (score 0):

Change `@style/appTheme.PopupOverlay` to `@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay`
You're mistaken in capital Letter

Comment: My apologies for the inconvenience, I had already written it up that way. That was only a silly typo.